# Access-Control-Allow-Origin issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I have two local rails apps that I would like to talk to each other for testing purposes... one is running on port 3000 and the other on 9292.

But when I make an ajax request from localhost:3000 to localhost:9292 I keep getting this issue:

`Origin http://localhost:3000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

Any idea on how to fix this?

I am using a simple Sinatra app to receive (for testing purposes ONLY) JSON requests. Below is how I got two rails apps talking to each other on localhost (one on port 3000 and the other on port 9292)
**Working Code**

```
before do
  headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
  headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, GET, OPTIONS'
  headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'X-Requested-With, X-Prototype-Version, X-CSRF-Token'
end

after do
  headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = 'http://localhost:3000/'
end
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Take a look at JSONP http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cross-domain AJAX is generally not allowed for security reasons. JSONP is an option if you are able to use it. If not, you can use something like [flXHR](http://flxhr.flensed.com/) to get around this restriction.

Best of luck!

Comment: I got it working by following this blog: http://www.tsheffler.com/blog/?p=428... I will edit my code base above

Comment: This is not correct. Cross site ajax is allowed if the server specifies that the origin is allowed in the response headers.

Comment: You're right, setting Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Allow-Methods, etc will allow cross domain ajax requests.

Answer (score 0):

for me, there was a 50X/40X Status coming back back Chrome/WebKit displayed a named Access-Control-Allow-Origin Error.

I played around with my responses until i got a 201 and now it works!